# Moving exactly 7 blocks from A to B.

Tags: combinatorics

[image]

I've never done a question like this in perms and coms (haven't even started the topic yet). There are two parts of the question and I don't know where to start!

We start from $A$. We are only allowed to move seven blocks exactly. We can only move in the directions northward and eastward.

a) How many possible routes are there from $A$ to $B$?

b) How many possible routes are there from $A$ to $B$, but you must go past $C$ before $B$?

Comment: Can you solve any part of this? For example, it should be easy to sketch all the possible routes from $A$ to $C$ and from $C$ to $B$ (which can be combined with each other in any way to get a route through $C$). Then perhaps you can find ways to get from $A$ to $B$ that don’t go through $C$. (Where might they go instead?)

Comment: Do you mean by "only allowed.." that the total number of moves must be exactly $7$ ?

Comment: @coffeemath yes exactly 7 moves

Comment: @SteveKass currently I'm drawing them out now to check the routes but I was wondering if there's a systematic approach with equations for in exam conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(a)$ Let move sequence be a binary string where $1$ denotes upward moves and $0$ denotes rightward moves. Then this binary string has length seven and it includes four $1$'s and three $0$'s. For example, $1111000$ or $0001111$. So part $(a)$ asks how many such binary strings are there and answer to this question is 
$$\binom{7}{4} = 35$$
because we are choosing the places for $1$'s and there are $7$ places in total. When we choose them, rest will be $0$ so actually it is $\binom{7}{4}\binom{3}{3} = \binom{7}{4}$.

$(b)$ Since it must pass from $C$, let us consider this problem in two parts. In the first part, let us find the ways from $A$ to $C$: With a similar logic to part $(a)$, there are $\binom{4}{3} = 4$ ways to go $C$ from $A$. Now, since we are in $C$, let's find the number of ways of going $B$ from $C$. This is $\binom{3}{2} = 3$. Therefore, we have $4 \cdot 3 = 12$ distinct ways.

**EDIT:** I read the comments and since the numbers are not so big in this case, you can consider part $(b)$ as the following:

[image]

Here, consider each curve as a different path in original question. Then you will eventually find the number of ways of going $B$ from $A$ in the above figure.

Comment: We haven't learnt catalan numbers yet and I haven't found it to be in our syllabus so do you think the interpreting the route into binary sequence would be a good technique to adapt to similar route-heavy questions? Thank you for your input! I think this is super cool.

Comment: Actually while I was using binary string method, I thought it is independent from catalan numbers and it is easy to interpret. Catalan numbers questions generally have different restrictions (such as number of upward moves cannot be larger than number of rightward moves), if you try to adapt this to such restriction, it would be harder to do of course. But if you ask for *similar route-heavy questions*, this is a good way yes. And you're welcome :)